# How do I distinguish between a "GOTO" version of an IF block and a "Structured" version of an IF block?

Tags: structured-programming

So I came across an old [blog post](https://8thlight.com/blog/uncle-bob/2015/09/23/a-little-structure.html) from Robert Martin (Uncle Bob) that talks about how the Structured Programming discipline convinced programmers to take the `GOTO` statement out of their code, even when its only implicit like in this example that he gave:

```
if (a>10)
  b++;
else
  b--;
```

He said that was bad practice because it basically would correlate to this code if written in FORTRAN:

```
    IF (A-10) 20,20,30
20  B = B - 1
    GOTO 40
30  B = B + 1
40  ...
```

To me, that makes sense. An `If` block essentially acts like a `GOTO` statement under the hood so why use it. (Of course, in the back of my mind, I'm thinking there's no way to get around some kind of `JUMP` instruction in the underlying assembly language, which is basically a `GOTO` statement, but I ignored that thought and moved on.)

But then he said:

> you could restrict your program to three different control structures: Sequence, Selection, and Iteration

and that with a `Selection` structure, you could write code like this:

```
if (someBooleanValue())
   doThisStep();
else
   doOtherStep();
```

That's supposed to be a better version of an `If` block than the `GOTO` version I mentioned above because it used a `Selection` structure. However, I don't really see the difference between them. What is the fundamental difference?

The only thing I can figure is that is has something to do with what he said here:

> Dijkstra's argument was that a structured program can be easily
>   analyzed because the state of the system at any line of code, depends
>   only on the **boolean values being tested** by selection and iteration,
>   and the list of calling procedures on the stack.

Somehow it seems like there is a deeper principle here that I'm missing. I get that you can keep track of the state of a program using boolean variables but what does that have to do with these two `If` blocks?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What is the fundamental difference?

There isn't one.

The reason your friend's argument falls apart is because *any* `if-else` can be rewritten using a `goto`.  In fact, at the processor level, *every* branch instruction (including the conditional ones) is a `goto`.

Structured programming is the act of using a structured programming language to write structured code, not musing about what the equivalent code in another language is, or what is happening under the language's hood.

Comment: So if there's no difference between those two `If` blocks, then I guess I'm trying to understand the deeper point of the article and the real value of structured programming. I think Uncle Bob was trying to compare/contrast the "awful" FORTRAN example with the "sequence, selection, and iteration" style of programming, but I just don't see the underlying principle he's trying to share. I guess that's a different question than the one I asked, but it's the one I was trying to formulate.

Comment: I suppose that the simple answer to that question is "strictly-structural languages don't contain goto instructions as part of their language specification."  Corollary: you don't need goto to write programs in such languages; you can write any such program using "sequence, selection and iteration," without ever involving a goto.  If you're still wondering why people care about this, look up Dijkstra's famous paper "Goto Considered Harmful."

Comment: Oh, I think you're right. I was reading too much into that part about FORTRAN. I thought he was saying something like "See _this_ Java example is the same as _this_ FORTRAN example, its just GOTO under the hood and that's bad. Here's the better way with structured programming." I guess he was actually saying "_This_ Java example represents the good code we write now. Compare that to _this_ bad FORTRAN code we used to write. Here's how we improved things: structured programming."

Comment: Yes, exactly ...